# Shared memory with array of structs to simulate a matrix in C

Tags: c, struct, ipc

I'm trying to fill the "cell" field of the shared array of structs with '*', but I keep obtaining a Segmentation fault error linked to the for-cicle.
I'm failing at understanding the usage of the shared memory, but I can't understand what the error is.
What I have to do is to print the map, but first I need the shared memory to work.
Thanks to everyone who will help me ^^

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define WIDTH 60
#define HEIGHT 20
#define LENGTH WIDTH*HEIGHT

typedef struct _Cell{
    int passthroughNum;
    int capacity;
    double passthroughTime;
    char cell;
} cell;

int main() {
    int i,shmap_id;
    char symbol = '*';
    cell *map;

    if((shmap_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, LENGTH, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget (map)");
    }
    map = (cell *)shmat(shmap_id, NULL, 0);
    if(map == (cell *)(-1)) {
        perror("shmat (map)");
    } 
    for(i=0;i<LENGTH;i++) {
        map[i].cell = symbol;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: cell is not one byte in size, so mapping LENGTH bytes will not get you enough space for LENGTH cells.

Comment: I'm so dumb, man! Thanks, I changed from LENGTH to sizeof(cell)*LENGTH and it's working! Thank you!